# python3.5 быстрее python3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, производительность

После просмотра видео http://pyvideo.org/pycon-belarus-2017/why-python-36-is-faster-than-python-35.html, решил проверить, для тестов выбрал вычисление факториала и сумму первых n членов последовательности Фибонначи. Вышло, что 3.6 медленнее на 10 - 15% чем 3.5.
Подумал может дело в том, что у меня Ubuntu 16.04, и с ней уже идет Python 3.5, а 3.6 я собирал из исходников.
Может есть что-то, что я упустил при сборке? Или как тогда эту разницу объяснить?

Для этого кода все выше описанное справедливо:

```
import time


n = 1

def recur(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return recur(n - 1) * recur(n - 1)

start = time.time()

recur(25)

print(str(time.time() - start))
```

Comment: Очень просто: Python не предназначен для математических вычислений :D

Comment: @andreymal во-первых, это не объясняет почему более старая версия _непредназначенного_ Python'а медленнее более новой. Во-вторых, вы сказали глупость, одно из основных назначений Python - это вычисления, он для этого очень широко применяется научным сообществом и множеством компаний по всему миру, в том числе гигантами типа Google.

Comment: 1- приведите код для benchmark (постарайтесь минимальный пример создать: `python3.Y -m perf timeit -s "L=range(1000)" "for _ in L: pass"`) 2- некоторые вещи в Питоне 3 медленнее чем даже в Питоне 2 3- соберите версии с похожими опциями (на некоторых задачах, руками пересобранный Питон был на порядок быстрее версии из дистрибутива Ubuntu. Попробуйте pythonz, pyenv, conda чтобы несколько версий поставить. 4- хорошее место для Питона: это исполняемый псевдо-код или клей, который различные компоненты соединяет: CPU интенсивные вещи обычно в С расширениях происходят (пример: numpy.dot)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev все вычисления в питоне, используемые вот этим вот научным сообществом, написаны не на питоне ;) Как пишет jfs выше, он всего лишь клей.

Comment: собирал с оптимизацией? у меня с оптимизацией собиралось 5 часов)))

Comment: Вы не можете делать выводы на основании одного замера. В первом случае у вас исполняемые файлы могли оказаться в кэше ФС, во втором нет, и наоборот. Есть тысячи вещей, которые влияют на бенчмарки, и их надо прибивать перед началом бенчмарка.

Comment: @jsf - добавил код в вопрос, он у меня с разницей в 1 секунду отрабатывает в пользу 3.5. То что Python2 быстрее Python3 это я уже давно заметил это ладно, это просто факт, но то что 3.6 еще медленнее чем 3.5 - неприятно (надеюсь просто это я не знаю всех возможностей сборки).

Comment: @etki это не единственный замер, а один из

Comment: окей, конкретно этот замер не говорит вообще ни о чем, и остальные, если они такие же или написаны схожим образом, тоже ни о чем не говорят

Comment: @eri пересобрал вот так ./configure --with-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install --with-zlib - результат тот же, или это не та оптимизация? Но собралось также быстро как и без флага --with-optimizations.

Comment: @etki - не спорю, но данное поведение стабильно, на массе примеров. Тогда каким образом можно переписать этот код, что бы он стал объективнее? (при прочих равных условиях)

Comment: я [не наблюдаю заметной разницы между 3.5.3 и 3.6.2 на вашем примере](https://gist.github.com/zed/683ca408a3a746cc8cd50dc842c484fa)